# Create mail with attachment using applescript and outlook

Tags: outlook, applescript

I've wrote a litte Applescript to make a new message with an attached file via outlook. But it didn't work and I don't know why. There is no error or something else. The message is created in the Draft-section of outlook, but the attachment is missing. Can somebody help me out?

Here's the Script:

```
set mailBody to "<span>TEST</span>" 

set mailAdress to text returned of (display dialog "Mail Adress" default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button 1) as string 

set whichFile to file
tell application "Finder" to set whichFile to selection
repeat with aFile in whichFile
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        set filename to name of aFile
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"TEST " & filename, content:mailBody}
        make new recipient at theNewMessage with properties {email address:{address:mailAdress}}
        set theAttachmentFile to aFile as POSIX file
        make new attachment at the end of theNewMessage with properties {file:theAttachmentFile}
        open theNewMessage
    end tell
end repeat
```

Greetings and thanks in advance

Speedster

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have been using as an alternative. To use the below, you need the desired message to be queued up already in your outbox. Or you can just borrow a few lines of the below and work it into your existing code.

set theAttachmentFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:Speedster:Documents:Attachment.docx" as alias
---replace this with the hard address of your selected file

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

```
repeat with theMessage in the messages of the outbox
    
    make new attachment at the end of theMessage with properties {file:theAttachmentFile}
    
end repeat
```

end tell